# Algebra and exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving a 7th grade math text book, and I came across this one:

If $a^x = b^y = c^z$, and $a^3 = b^2 c$, then what is $\displaystyle \frac{3}{x} - \frac{2}{y}$?

I tried:
--> $\displaystyle c = \frac{a^3}{b^2} \Rightarrow a = \sqrt[3]{b^2c} \Rightarrow b = \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{c}}$

But I couldn't arrive at a conclusion, and I also thought there should be a simpler way of solving this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a^x=b^y=c^z=d^{xyz}$$
$$\implies a=d^{yz}\text{ etc.} $$

So, $$(d^{yz})^3=(d^{zx})^2\cdot d^{xy}\implies d^{3yz}=d^{2zx+xy}\implies 3yz=2zx+xy$$

Divide either sides by $xyz$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^3=b^2c$, we have
$$(a^3)^{xyz}=(b^2c)^{xyz}\iff a^{3xyz}=b^{2xyz}c^{xyz}\iff a^{3xyz}=(b^y)^{2xz}(c^z)^{xy}$$$$\iff a^{3xyz}=(a^x)^{2xz}+(a^x)^{xy}\iff a^{3xyz}=a^{2x^2z+x^2y}.$$

Hence, we have
$$3xyz=2x^2z+x^2y.$$

Finally, dividing the both sides by $x^2yz$ will give you
$$\frac 3x=\frac 2y+\frac 1z\iff \frac 3x-\frac 2y=\frac 1z.$$